# gets not working for large strings in ruby

Tags: ruby, stdin

I am doing some coding on online coding platforms. While taking a large string a input from STDIN I am using `gets` but I am getting only a string of length max 1024.

any suggestion for better way to take input. Or is it possible or not?

Basically I have a code which works on array and Testcase array is provide through STDIN, and elements in one of the test case is 10000 so string length is roughly 40000.

```
arr = gets.split
```

Above is the code I am having problem with.

Comment: I don't think this is a "ruby issue" per se. Most terminals have an input buffer size of 1kb or similar, which is why you can't send more without a newline (on your specific machine). Can you show us your code, explain what problem you're *actually* trying to solve (why are you sending so much data over a `gets` command?), and hopefully we can at least reproduce it? See: [mcve].

Comment: @TomLord I am trying to get input array from STDIN using gets. arr = gets.split and my input string is around 40000 characters. Can you suggest any way to get these large input strings?

Comment: Why are you trying to get a 40,000 single-line input over STDIN?! What data is it? Where is it coming from? Could you not just, for example, read a file that contains the data?

Comment: I am trying to solve a online coding problem, it has its one of the test case with 40000 chars, You can check it at https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/equal

Comment: Ahh, OK... Yeah, that's a pretty unusual requirement then, especially for ruby. If the above "duplicate" answer doesn't work, you could also try using `Open3` - or even just "bend the rules" and read from a file rather that STDIN - since the real purpose of the challenge is in designing the algorithm, not handling an input buffer!

Comment: agreed with what you say.